# Yii 2 Menu Display List Depending on User

Tags: php, menu, navbar, yii2

How do I configure or customize my Menu where in, for example, if I am an **admin** user, I can see everything on my navigation bar, like, in my case, the **Users** (list of Users where I can create, update, or delete one), **Stores** (just like Users, this is where I can configure a specific store), **Transactions** and then the **Logout** button. But when an **ordinary user/staff** logs in, the only thing he/she will see is the **Transactions** menu and a **Logout** button as well.

Please help.

**Edit**:
Here is my menu rendering code:

```
<?php
    echo Menu::widget([
        'options' => ['id' => "nav-mobile", 'class' => 'right side-nav'],
        'items' => [
          ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['/site/index']],
          ['label' => 'About', 'url' => ['/site/about']],
          ['label' => 'Contact', 'url' => ['/site/contact']],
          Yii::$app->user->isGuest ?
              ['label' => 'Login', 'url' => ['/site/login']] :
              ['label' => 'Logout (' . Yii::$app->user->identity->username . ')',
                  'url' => ['/site/logout'],
                  'linkOptions' => ['data-method' => 'post']
              ],
      ],
    ]);
?>
```

Comment: How user role is determined in your application? Did you implement RBAC? Or for example role stored in users table in separate column?

Comment: Hi @arogachev, I didn't use RBAC. I used that second one you mentioned where I stored a user_type of a user in a specific column of my users table.

Comment: Show menu rendering code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each item in `items` array has `visible` property. Pass expression returning boolean value there.

```
'items' => [
    // Show users section for administrators only
    [
        'label' => 'Users',
        'url' => ['/users/index'],
        'visible' => !Yii::$app->user->isGuest && Yii::$app->user->identity->user_type == User::USER_TYPE_SUPER_ADMIN,
    ],
],
```

Yoy can also put this condition in additional model method to avoid repeating, something like `isAdmin()` in `User` model.

Official documentation:

- [$items](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-menu.html#$items-detail)

Comment: I simply pasted `'visible' => Yii::$app->user->identity->role == User::ROLE_ADMIN,` in my code and I got this error: `Getting unknown property: app\models\User::role`

Comment: It's just an example, correct it according to your names.

Comment: What do I put instead in the `USER_TYPE_ADMIN` constant?

Comment: How you determine admin by `user_type`?

Comment: My `user_type` can be `SuperAdmin`, `BizAdmin` or `BizStaff`. I put them on `enum` in my database (phpmyadmin)

Comment: So declare constants if they don't exist and simply correct check depending on necessary value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70996/discussion-between-kaynewilder-and-arogachev).

Comment: Hello. I replied again to the chat.

Comment: User::USER_TYPE_SUPER_ADMIN, I can't understand this.actually in my User table type field is enum('v','B')

Answer (score 1):

I think this function is also usefully here

**\Yii::$app->user->can("BackendUsersIndex")**

```
'items' => [
    // Show users section for administrators only
    [
        'label' => 'Users',
        'url' => ['/users/index'],
        'visible' => \Yii::$app->user->can("BackendUsersIndex"),
    ],
],
```